# Questions regarding the following initial value problem

Tags: integration, initial-value-problems

I want to solve the initial value problem:

\begin{cases}
\dfrac{dx}{dt} + 2x(t) = f(t), t > 0 \\
x(0) = x_0  \\
\end{cases}

I start off by finding the integrating factor, which is $ e^{2t}$. Multiplying both sides with the integrating factor and using the chain rule gives me following:

$ \Big(x(t) * e^{2t} \Big)' = f(t) * e^{2t}  $

Now i set $t = \tau$ and integrate both sides, i get

$$ \int_0^t\Big(x(\tau) * e^{2\tau} \Big)' \ d\tau  =  \int_0^t\Big(f(\tau) * e^{2\tau} \Big) \ d\tau$$

From this i get that

$$ \left [x(\tau)  e^{2\tau} \right]_{0}^{t}  = \int_0^t\Big(f(\tau) * e^{2\tau} \Big) \ d\tau$$
and then from this we get that

$$ x(t) = e^{-2t}x_0 +\int_0^t\Big(f(\tau) * e^{-2(t-\tau)} \Big) \ d\tau $$ which is the solution.

I have to following questions:

- Why do we set $ t = \tau $?

Also, why do i get that $$ \left [x(\tau)  e^{2\tau} \right]_{0}^{t} = \int_0^t\Big(f(\tau) * e^{2\tau} \Big) \ d\tau $$

The way i always learned to solve IVP with integrating factor is that

$$ \int\Big(x(t) * e^{2t} \Big)' = x(t) * e^{2t}  $$ since the integral and the derivative cancel each other out, so why don't is the following wrong?

$$ x(t) * e^{2t}  = \int f(t) * e^{2t}$$

Hopefully someone will understand what i mean. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note, I personally find $*$ very confusing as it's the symbol for convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $t=\tau$ distinguishes the limits of integration from the variable of integration, which is a dummy variable.

The final indefinite integral would introduce a constant of integration and doesn't allow you to compute $x(t)$ without finding that constant. Using the definite integrals, the constant doesn't appear, it cancels out, and you have an explicit formula for $x(t)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I still have a hard time understanding why we set $ t=\tau $. I have been searching for material that explains it in greater detail, but i can't seem to find any. Is this method called something? Do you maybe know where i can find more on this topic? Once again, thanks!

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html may be helpful.

Comment: I have one last question. I hope it is fine. In the IVP where \begin{cases}
\dfrac{dx}{dt} + \dfrac{1}{t}x(t) = e^{t^2} t > 0 \\
x(1) = 1  \\
\end{cases}, i get that the integral and derivative cancel each other out, and i don't have to pay attention to the limits of the integration. Why is this the case here, but not in the first problem? Is it because in this case we can actually determine the integral of the right side? Thanks a lot!